# How concatenate two string in Spring Expression Language (SpEL)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-el

In my spring application, the methods from my controller and service classes have this annotation to security purposes:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra')")
```

the second argument, the permission, should have this format:

```
<<action_name>>_<<class_name>>
```

What expression I should use to accomplish that, taking in consideration the class name is held by `this.getClass().getName()`?

Comment: Do you mean this doesn't work: `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_' + this.class.name)")`?

Comment: I try exactly this way and don't work. Before this, I also try use: `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_#this.class.name')")`unsuccessfully.

Comment: A combination of those two suggestions perhaps: `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user,'cadastra_'+#this.class.name)")`

Comment: yes, I try this too, but I got access denied in all cases. Is there any way to verify which the final value for this string is receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solve this. I add a new method in my controller:

```
public String getName() {
    String nome_classe = entityClass.getSimpleName();
    System.out.println("getName nome_class = "+nome_classe);
    return nome_classe;
}
```

and now I use the annotation in that way:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
```

Answer (score 18):

To concatenate two strings in Spring EL you use `concat` function . See here for more details : 
[Spring EL docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-evaluation)

for example, I used the following :

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_'.concat(this.class.simpleName))")
```

Answer (score 0):

If one of the strings is a variable, you can do this:

```
EvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
ctx.setVariable("lat", 30.3);
ctx.setVariable("lng", 110.00);
// https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-variables
String loc = ep.parseExpression("'{\"lng\":'.concat(#lng).concat(',\"lat\":').concat(#lat).concat('}')").getValue(ctx, String.class);
```

the result is:

```
{"lng":110.0,"lat":30.3}
```