# Submiting a object from a Html Form

Tags: java, html, forms, spring, generics

In my spring project, I have the follow form, from where I need submit to server a new entity:

```
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp" %>

<form:form class="form" role="form" action="${action}" method="post">

    <table>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${elements}">
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="${item}">${item}</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="" path="${item}" /></td> 
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>

<%@ include file="../include/result.jsp" %>

<%@ include file="../include/footer.jsp" %>
```

the form submit the data for this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(serv.cadastra(object))
        return "yes";
    else
        return "not";
}
```

where `object` is supposed to be a generic parent class to all my entity classes.

Is there any way to make this work? This method is from a generic controller, each specialized controller will replace `E` by the name of your specific entity class (derived from object).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How concatenate two string in Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121277/how-concatenate-two-string-in-spring-expression-language-spel)